# Examples of discontinuous embeddings between Hilbert spaces

Tags: functional-analysis

I am looking for an example of a discontinuous embedding $H_1 \rightarrow H_2$, where $H_1,H_2$ are Hilbert spaces and $H_1 \subset H_2$. In other words, for any $C > 0$, we can find $x \in H_1$ such that $\Vert x \Vert _{H _1} = 1$ and $\Vert x \Vert _{H _2} > C$.

[This wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_embedding) gives an example of a discontinuous embedding $C^0([0,1], \mathbb{R}) \rightarrow C^0([0,1], \mathbb{R})$, the former equipped with the $L^1$ norm and the latter equipped with the $L^{\infty}$ norm. However, they are not Hilbert spaces. I am looking for an example for two Hilbert spaces.

Comment: What do you mean by "embedding"? Injective linear map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In many "reasonable" situations, this is not possible due the closed graph theorem. Let us denote the embedding by $A$, i.e., $A \colon H_1 \to H_2$ is linear.
Then, $A$ has a closed graph, provided that
for all sequences $(x_k) \subset H_1$ with
$$
x_k \to x \text{ in } H_1, \qquad A(x_k) \to y \text{ in } H_2,$$
we have $y = A(x)$. In many situations, this is satisfied and the closed graph theorem yields that $A$ is continuous.
Note that this property just means, that if you have a sequence $(x_k) \subset H_1 \subset H_2$ which converges in $H_1$ and in $H_2$, then the limits have to coincide.

However, there are artificial examples, which do not satisfy the above, see here: https://mathoverflow.net/a/184471.

Comment: Thanks. This is all I need to know.

Comment: This does not answer the question: 1) For a linear map $A:H_1\to H_2,$ bounded $\iff$  continuous $\iff$ closed graph, but this is off topic. The question is whether there exist an injective discontinuous $A.$ 2) Your link to mathoverflow does not provide a counterexample with *Hilbert* spaces.

Comment: -1: the question asks for a discontinuous embedding and the answer takes as an assumption that the embedding is continuous.

Comment: @AnneBauval: I do not understand your objections. 1) Yes, of course continuous is equivalent to closed graph. But my reasoning is that this fact is a serious obstruction to the existence of discontinuous embeddings, since most embeddings have a closed graph. 2) If you start with a Hilbert space $X$, the construction gives you an example with Hilbert spaces.

Comment: @MartinArgerami: Where did I assume a continuous embedding? I only explained that most embeddings are continuous because they have a closed graph. I also gave an example of a discontinuous embedding (or at least pointed to such a construction).

Comment: +1 Thank you for mentionning that in the answer you linked to, "If you start with a Hilbert space $X$, the construction gives you an example with Hilbert spaces". I was too lazy to notice. I think this is the main part of your answer (if not the only relevant one, the rest being more or less tautologic), and should be made more explicit (the construction itself could even be copied here, for the reader's convenience).

Comment: @gerw: in your second sentence, when you said that $A$ is bounded.

Comment: @MartinArgerami: Ups. This "bounded" should actually read "linear"...